# How to provide Redshift Database Password in Python Script in AWS Datapipeline?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-data-pipeline

I am using Redshift and have to write some custom scripts to generate reports. I am using AWS datapipeline CustomShellActivity for running my custom logic. I am using python and boto3. I am wondering what is the safest way and in fact, best practice to provide database password in python script. I am sure that hardcoding password in script is not good practice. What other options do I have or should I explore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pretty standard approach is to [store credentials](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/109927/securely-storing-an-encryption-key-on-aws) in a secure S3 bucket and download them as part of the deployment/launch process using an IAM role with access to the secure bucket. For limited runtime cases like lambda or datapipeline you could download from S3 to an in [memory buffer using](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html#module-boto.s3.key) `boto.Key.get_contents_as_string()` at startup, parse the file and set up your credentials.

For increased security you can incorporate [KMS secret management](https://blog.fugue.co/2015-04-21-aws-kms-secrets.html). Here is [an example](https://github.com/codahale/sneaker) that combines the two.

Answer (score 0):

I usually store them as an environment variables. I am not sure about the AWS data pipeline deployment, but on a standard Linux box (EC2), you could do:

```
# ~/.profile or /etc/profile
export MY_VAR="my_value"
```

And then you can access them in Python like this:

```
# python script
import os
my_var_value = os.environ['MY_VAR'] if 'MY_VAR' in os.environ else 'default'
```

Comment: Might not be a good idea as the access to the server by default grants access to AWS credentials.